# Solr version upgrade from solr 5.5 to solr 6.6.6 results increasing the query time

Tags: solr, solrcloud

While upgrading the solr from version 5.5 to 6.6, we observe the query time has been increased.

I wanted to ask, Is this normal behavior on solr 6.6.6, or was there some setting that we forgot to add?

Examples:

(Solr 6.6.6 version)

TimeTaken in Milliseconds: 838
Documents found in SOLR: 125

TimeTaken in Milliseconds: 105
Documents found in SOLR: 165813

TimeTaken in Milliseconds: 178
Documents found in SOLR: 6708

TimeTaken in Milliseconds: 252
Documents found in SOLR: 494679

(Solr 5.5 version)

TimeTaken in Milliseconds:11
Documents found in SOLR: 249

TimeTaken in Milliseconds:38
Documents found in SOLR: 120826

TimeTaken in Milliseconds:15
Documents found in SOLR: 3955

TimeTaken in Milliseconds:59
Documents found in SOLR: 521061

Pleas also tell us do we need to add any settings corresponding to solr 6.6.6 version.

Pleas also tell us do we need to add any settings corresponding to solr 6.6.6 version.

Comment: Did you reindex? The differing number of documents also seems weird if it's the same index; you also need to go through the changelog to see what is affecting you (.. and then start the work on getting to Solr 7, then 8, then 9).

Comment: @MatsLindh Where do we find the changelog.what does the changelog mean.Can you please explain

Comment: The changelog shows everything that has changed between different versions of an application or library. It's a log of changes. You can see the changelog for 6.6.6 here: https://solr.apache.org/docs/6_6_6/changes/Changes.html (or for all versions up to 9.1: https://solr.apache.org/docs/9_1_0/changes/Changes.html). The changelogs also reference the upgrading notes for each version iirc.